# TextView's text alignment

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget33"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/widget34"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget35"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:gravity="center" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget36"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:gravity="center" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget37"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:gravity="center" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The text in `TextViews` is not aligned to the `centre` even though the `gravity` is set `center`.Text is shifted to extreme right.When I check the same code in droidDraw every thing seems fine.Whats happening?

Comment: Everything is working fine after I restarted eclipse.Thanx everyone

Answer (score 0):

as long as you use `wrap_content` for `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`, the gravity does not do anything.

Comment: when I do strecthColumns on table layout it automatically stretched each column i.e textView here.When I click on a TextView now the highlight is showing the outline which clearly not wrapcontent.What you said is true if I don't use stretch columns

Comment: Every thing working fine now after I restarted eclipse.Might be some bug

Answer (score 0):

//Try with

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you set TextView to wrap_content it takes up as small space as posible. When you set it to center it centers inside the wrap_content. This makes it seem that there is no difference.

If you set TextView to fill or match_parent it will center inside the TableLayout.